# ¿Como hago where con campo de fecha mes proyectado?

Tags: php, sql, select, sum

Tengo 2 tablas: tabla1 (documento, fecha_inicio, grupo) y tabla 2 con los detalles (documento, fecha_act, actividades) en la tabla1, son unicos registros, en la tabla2 se repite N veces las actividades, y deseo buscar en 150 dias de registrado(inicio) que actividades realizo o no, Con Documento A0010,01/01/2020,aa, en la tabla2 pueda o no existir las actividades (A001, 10/06/2020, act11),(A001, 08/06/2020, act11). entiendo que debo hacer un inner o left join, pero no puedo hacer la condicion de sumar los dias o extraer el mes del resultado de esos dias para medir

Comment: Agrega que has intentado

Comment: Y el dataset (phpMyAdmin->Exportar), con la estructura de tu base de datos, algunos datos y el resultado que esperas para esos datos de muestra